# "Spring" wpf slider control

Tags: wpf, slider

how can i make in Wpf 4 -"Spring"-slider control?
the Thumb always  back to set point 0,
after Release the Thumb , it jump like "spring" to the beginning.
Cheers
Diu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use triggers to do this in XAML (which is just springing back on the release of the thumb with a duration of a second)

```
        <Slider x:Name="slider">
        <Slider.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger SourceName="slider" RoutedEvent="Thumb.DragCompleted">    
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="slider" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Value" From="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider}" To="0" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>          
            </EventTrigger>
        </Slider.Triggers>              
    </Slider>
```

However, this won't capture clicks on the slider for steps or direct setting of the Value property. To fully capture this you would need to listen to all three events (Thumb.DragCompleted, Thumb.DragStarted and Slider.ValueChanged) and make sure that you don't apply any animations while the thumb is being dragged. You would also want to customise the duration of the animation as currently it has a constant time, rather than constant speed.

Although it would be possible to do fully within XAML, you may find it easier to use code-behind to achieve a fully functional implementation of a 'springy' slider.

Comment: Hey Diu, looks like there was an issue with the defaultt evaluation of the From property, which an explicit binding resolves (updated solution to reflect this). DoubleAnimation has a default duration of 1 second, but you can set Duration="0:0:0" if you want it to immediately reset the slider to zero without any animation.